# Signal r not working after updating to .net core 2.2

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, .net-core, signalr

We use signal r to drive our front end for updates and it was working 100% until we upgraded to .net core 2.2

See the startup below, the methods do get called and normal back end calls work work without a problem but as soon as Signal r tries to connect from the front end i get a cors error.

I have tried to just allow all through cors but that also didn't work.

```
protected IServiceProvider ConfigureServicesImplementation(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<DatabaseConfiguration>(Configuration.GetSection(DatabaseConfigurationName));
        services.Configure<TokenProviderConfiguration>(Configuration.GetSection(TokenProviderConfigurationName));
        services.AddOptions();
        services.AddCors();
        services.AddAutoMapper();
        services.AddAutofac();

        services.AddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();
        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

        services.AddScoped<DatabaseMigrator>();
        services.AddScoped<AdminTenantDbInitialiser>();
        services.AddScoped<TenantDbInitialiser>();
        services.AddScoped<HubBase>();
        services.AddScoped<HubService>();

        services.AddSignalR()
        .AddJsonProtocol(options =>
            {
                options.PayloadSerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter
                {

                });
            });

        services.AddDbContext<DefaultDbContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetSection(DatabaseConfigurationName)["ConnectionString"]);
        });
        services.AddDbContext<TenantDbContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetSection(DatabaseConfigurationName)["TenantManagementConnectionString"]);
        });

        services.AddMemoryCache();
        services.AddHealthChecks();

        ConfigureAuthImplementation(services);
        ConfigureMvcImplementation(services);

        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.Load("Digitise.Domain.Services"))
                      .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                      //.InstancePerRequest()
                      .PropertiesAutowired();

        builder.Populate(services);

        var container = builder.Build();

        return new AutofacServiceProvider(container);
    }

    private void ConfigureMvcImplementation(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var mvc = services.AddMvcCore(options =>
        {
            options.Filters.Add(new ProducesAttribute("application/json"));
            options.Filters.Add(typeof(ValidateModelAttribute));
        })
            .AddApiExplorer()
            .AddAuthorization()
            .AddDataAnnotations()
            .AddJsonFormatters()
            .AddControllersAsServices()
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
            .AddJsonOptions(options =>
            {
                options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter
                {

                });
            });

        if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            var controllers = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
            .Where(type => typeof(ControllerBase).IsAssignableFrom(type))
            .ToList();

            var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();
            foreach (var controllerType in controllers)
            {
                var controller = sp.GetService(controllerType);
            }
        }

        mvc.AddFluentValidation(fv =>
        {
            fv.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<UserLoginInputValidator>();
            fv.RunDefaultMvcValidationAfterFluentValidationExecutes = false;
            fv.ImplicitlyValidateChildProperties = true;
        });
    }

    protected void ConfigureApp(IApplicationBuilder app, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment env, IMapper autoMapper, bool addTenantRoute = false)
    {

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseSwaggerUi3(x => { });
            //autoMapper.ConfigurationProvider.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/error");
            app.UseHsts();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        }

        app.UseCors(builder => builder
           .AllowAnyOrigin()
           .AllowAnyMethod()
           .AllowAnyHeader()
           .AllowCredentials());

        app.UseSignalR(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapHub<HubBase>("/globalhub");
        });

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            if (addTenantRoute)
            {
                routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller}/{action}/{tenant?}/{id?}", defaults: new
                {
                    controller = "app",
                    action = "ping"
                });
            }
            else
            {
                routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller}/{action}/{id?}", defaults: new
                {
                    controller = "app",
                    action = "ping"
                });
            }
            routes.MapRoute(name: "ping", template: "app/ping", defaults: new { controller = "App", action = "Ping" });
        });

        app.UseAuthentication();
    }
```

[image: request]

[image: Response error]

as for Connecting from the front end please see the code below.

```
public startHubConnection(): void {
    if (!this.hubConnection) {
        const currentUser = this.authenticationService.getCurrentUser();
        this.hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl(this.url + '/globalhub?Authorization=Bearer ' + currentUser.accessToken).build();
    }

    this.hubConnection
        .start()
        .then(() => {
            this.isHubConnected = true;
            if (this.firstRun) {
                this.firstRun = false;
                this.manageHubConnections();
            }

            this.hubReconnectAllowed = true;
            this.serverStatusChange.emit(true);
            if (this.hubReconnectionId) {
                this.isHubConnected = true;
                this.notificationService.success('Server online', 'Reconnect with server successfull.');
                this.globalService.systemOnline = true;
                clearInterval(this.hubReconnectionId);
            }
        })
        .catch(err => console.dir('manual: ' + err));
}
```

Comment: What SignalR package/version are you using?

Comment: Seems like cross origin issue both UI and service domain address are different, Please handle Preflight request like  -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request

Comment: We are on version 1.1.0 on server and client

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So in 2.2 .AllowAnyOrigin() + .AllowCredentials() is no longer allowed as it is insecure. You need to explicitly set the allowed origins using WithOrigins().
Problem solved thanks to BrennanConroy

[Article](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/4483)

Answer (score 0):

CORS Middleware must precede any defined endpoints in your application where you want to support cross-origin requests so you should invoke `UseCors` before `UseSignalR`:

```
...

app.UseCors(builder => builder
   .AllowAnyOrigin()
   .AllowAnyMethod()
   .AllowAnyHeader()
   .AllowCredentials());

app.UseSignalR(routes =>
{
    routes.MapHub<HubBase>("/globalhub");
});

...
```

Comment: tried it. the negotiate returns no content in network and still throws the cors error on console.

Comment: @Arno4Jackie it's the same error code as before change order of method invocation? Did nothing change at all?

Comment: nope nothing changed at all. i moved the cors to be on top of the use signal r